# How to create and use a text file in Python?

Tags: python, text-files

I need to create a text file in Python to store certain data from a game. I do not want to use numpy, or any external libraries if at all possible.

I need to put some numerical data. Do text files require string data? Also does the data come out of the file as a string?

I know how to create and open a text file, and how to convert string to integer and vice versa, as well as handle CSV file data. I do not know how to handle a text file.

Any ideas on what to do?

Comment: Read the manual: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: Hey, check out this: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp

Comment: How about using `pickle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a file:

```py
file = open("textfile.txt","w+")
```

This will create a file if it doesn't exist in the directory.

To write inside it:

```py
file.write("This is the content of the file.")
```

And then you'll have to close the instance with

```py
file.close()
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. I thought you may have had to have used an external libary, like csv. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

by using the `with open` command you can create and use it

here is an example

Here w is for writing mode

```
with open('test.txt','w') as d:
   d.write('your text goes here')
```

You can write to file like this if the file not exists then it will be created

Answer (score 0):

*Any ideas on what to do?*
Put your data into `dict` and use built-in [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module, example:

```
import json
data = {'gold': 500, 'name': 'xyzzy'}
# writing
with open('save.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
# reading
with open('save.json', 'r') as f:
    data2 = json.load(f)
```

This create human-readable text file.